# what, exactly, does data-anchor-target do?

Tags: skrollr

I'm playing around with Skrollr and for the most part it seems pretty intuitive, the one thing that kind of gets me is the data-anchor-target attribute. Most times I don't need it but when I look at some examples it's usually included and I'm confused as to what it does. Does it just mean that at that target, that's when the Skrollr data-(pos) attributes kick in?

Comment: I thought this example would be self explanatory http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/anchor_target.html

Comment: let me know if i'm wrong prinzhorn, but it basically means all the data attributes you add to the child element are in relation to the data target

Answer (score 4):

`data-anchor-target`   When using Skrollr.js, you normally use one of two methods as inputs for starting and stopping scrolling controls:

1. Absolute positioning, relating to the start or the end of the
   entire document.
2. Relative positioning, relating to the top,
   bottom or center of the viewing browser frame.

The `data-anchor-target` tag enables the developer the freedom to use an alternative element to trigger a modification.  You place the control position directly inside the document.  Elements are identified to the target tag with simple CSS selectors (.class or #id's).  When the `data-anchor-target` tag element is scrolled into the viewing window, the developer can use the normal relative mode `data-bottom-top` tag to start the desired scrolling result.  Use `data-top-bottom` as a control for when the data-anchor-target scrolls up and out of the viewing window. Remember this image?

[image: pictorial]

This is way cool, as this enables perfect control for different viewing devices, orientations and screen sizes.   Take a look at the anchor-target.html example.  Notice how the blue face smiles whenever the red face is visible in frame?  (Note: don't get freaked out by the `!0` CSS identifier in that sample.  Remember in skroller,  the `!` exclamation symbol is used to fix a numeric field from modifying during scrolling.  )