# How to use data-anchor-target in skrollr?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, skrollr

I've seen Skrolllr's capabilities and I must say i'm impressed with the ease of use. I'm trying to use this on my next website build but can't seem to get what `data-anchor-target` do exactly? Here's the code, foremost:

```
<body>
<img data-anchor-target="#topbar" data-0="opacity:0;" data-top-top="opacity:1;" class="logo-half" src="images/logo-banner-1.png">
<div class="container-fluid" id="skrollr-body">
    <div id="home" class="intro-slider">
        <div><img src="images/slide1.jpg" width="100%"></div>
        <div><img src="images/slide2.jpg" width="100%"></div>
        <div><img src="images/slide3.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="topbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bwd-school-nav">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo-banner-2.png"></a>
            </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bwd-school-nav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#courses">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = skrollr.init({
         forceHeight: false,
    });
</script>

</body>
```

I'm trying to make an image (logo-banner-1.png) appear on screen when the scroll reaches a certain point. Defining specific values work fine:
`data-0="opacity:0;" data-350="opacity:0;" data-400="opacity:1;"` but since my website is responsive, fixed values or even percentages won't work. The position has to be relative to  the content.

Here the first `div` is an image slider, then a navigation bar. I want the image to start appearing slightly before the navigation reaches the top and be completely visible when the navigation reaches the top. Here's the code I used:

`<img data-anchor-target="#topbar" data-0="opacity:0;" data-top-top="opacity:1;" class="logo-half" src="images/logo-banner-1.png">` and

`<img data-anchor-target="#topbar" data-0="opacity:0;" data--50-top-top="opacity:0;" data-top-top="opacity:1;" class="logo-half" src="images/logo-banner-1.png">`

but none of these work. I've also seen [this example](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/anchor_target.html) and tried the code but it still doesn't work. What is wrong with my code? Can anyone explain if I'm using `data-anchor-target` wrong?

I'm including the link to my the page where you can see this in action. The link might not work for long though: http://www.bestwebsitedesigners.net/testbench/skrollr-demo.html

Comment: Also looking for a solution like this. But from my google reserach I dont think this is how the data-anchor-target works, it has to involve a `position: fixed` element. Please share if you find a solution :) I'll do the same!

Comment: Was looking for the same info and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621281/what-exactly-does-data-anchor-target-do